# Using PYODBC from Windows WSL

Tags: python, pyodbc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows WSL and am trying to configure python to connect to MSSQL

I have installed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

But when I run the example connection as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "users.py", line 9, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', u"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

File exists:

```
 khinester@win  /c/Users/norman/Projects/sysadmin   master ? ↑1 ⍟2  ls /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1                                          ✔  5619  15:52:53
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18M Jul  3  2018 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
```

Any advice on how to fix this is much appreciated

Comment: too bad no replies to this. did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I know this is a dead thread, but you get that error most likely because you installed the ODBC Driver 18 and in the connection you call the 17 version

Comment: Did you check the access rights? Not sure how WSL handles these in combination with pyodbc: https://chmod-calculator.com/ Maybe you need to modify the access rights or add a certain user to a group?